# Loading a local JSON file using script tag

Tags: javascript, json, local

I want to load a JSON file locally into my HTML page, without using a web server. This isn't possible with AJAX so I came up with this solution:

HTML:

```
<script src="../js/hack.js"></script>
<script src="../js/data.json"></script>
```

Inside hack.js :

```
var myJsonData =
```

And the json file looks like this:

```
[{"something":"anything"},{},{}]
```

I expected that the ultimate result would be this:

```
var myJsonData = [{"something":"anything"},{},{}]
```

But sadly I get the error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input** after loading 'hack.js'.

Is there any way to solve this without adjusting the json file, and without adjusting the local browser settings / using a localhost server?

Comment: Save that file as `data.js` and try to get the value!

Comment: You cannot expect that the files are just concatinated. Each file is parsed as a seperated script, you can use each others variables, but there is no overflow from the code

Comment: you cannot do like this..you need to have an ajax call to the json to get the values from it and then fill myJsonData variable with the json data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18278346/609907

Comment: He is using the code localy, he isn't able to do ajax requests.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change your json file so that you declare the variable there.

**data.json**

```
var MyjsonData = [{"something":"anything"},{},{}]
```

Now in your `hack.js` file, you can call the variable `MyjsonData`.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably the only solution. I was hoping for a way to avoid altering the JSON file itself.