# Set Variable Equal to Object Stored In Another File (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php

I have an object defined in a .js file, which is done via PHP on the server side.

I would like to know how to set a variable equal to this object, because the JS file doesn't actually define anything, it is just the object...

EX: (this is my .js file on my server)

```
{  
"Title": {"Link" = "http://example.com", "img" = "http://imgurl.com"},
 "Title2": {"Link" = "http://blahblah.com", "img" = "http://imgurl.com"}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what we call a JSON file. You can parse it with [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

As for how to get the content of the file dynamically, you could use the JQuery function [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) or work the AJAX yourself, but I don't know a lot about that.

Comment: If it is stored on my server as a .js, how could I download it and parse it? Alright thanks, ill try it :)

Comment: I've edited my answer. Since you didn't tag that question JQuery though, I guess it wont help.

Comment: I know a bit about jqery, it should work for what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! I've also found this other question, might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838812/how-can-i-open-a-json-file-in-javascript-without-jquery