# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token while reading JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, json

My JSON file is:

```
{
    "myjson": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "x"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "y"
    }]
}
```

And my HTML file to read it is like this:

```
<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
function myjson(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<a href="' + arr[i].id + '">' + arr[i].name + '</a><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

<script src="js/myjson.json"></script>
```

But I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in line 2`

I can't change the JSON file, How can I solve the problem by changing HTML/JS code?

Comment: The JSON is invalid. The last property of an object does not have a semicolon after its value. See http://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: In addition, you can find such errors by using http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I solve that problem, but still I can't read it

Comment: Wait, wait, the JSON is valid according to JSON lint but your code does not show us how you parse it at all. There is just a function inside your code, it never gets called and it does not even decode JSON anywhere.

Comment: @somethinghere now the JSON is valid he edited his post, before it was not.

Comment: How are you reading `external` json file ? When are you calling `myjson` function ?

Comment: You should load json file using ajax request and store the result into a variable and then call myjson method over that variable.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is first parse the JSON file, then use your function for the array.
You can get the JSON from a file by using JQuery like this:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

```
$.getJSON("js/myjson.json", function(json){
    // json is an object which contains the array called "myjson"
    // now you can pass that array into your function like this:
    myjson(json.myjson);
})
```

If you don't want to use JQuery look how it's done without here:

[How can I open a JSON file in JavaScript without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838812/how-can-i-open-a-json-file-in-javascript-without-jquery)

**Edit:** Okay lets do it as a whole.

HTML:

```
<div id="id01"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function myjson(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<a href="' + arr[i].id + '">' + arr[i].name + '</a><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}

function loadJSON(path, success, error)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                if (success)
                    success(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            } else {
                if (error)
                    error(xhr);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", path, true);
    xhr.send();
}

loadJSON('js/myjson.json', function(data){ myjson(data.myjson);}, function(xhr) {console.error(xhr); });
```

You can either put your Javascript inside your HTML with a script tag like

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">//Javascript goes here</script>
```

or put it into a seperate file and just link it in your HTML like this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></script>
```

Comment: **parse the JSON file** ?

Comment: @RayonDabre JQuery does that for you already. If you would get it as a string you would have to use JSON.parse(string) first to convert it into an object.

Comment: [Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)

Comment: @Quentin Edited in a solution without JQuery.

Comment: I get a bit confused, how should my HTML/JS code be right now ? to read that file

Comment: I assume you are not using JQuery Anderson? And if I understand you correctly you have the JSON located in one file and want to load it from there into your HTML page?

Comment: @user2415266 You have already put in _way more_ effort than necessary. There are dozens of questions about this on SO with great answers. +1 for you and boo to the downvoters.

Comment: @user2415266 yes that is, I should read that file on the server and load it's content in my HTML page. I did what you say, but it has an error : data is not defined

Comment: That is because I messed up, sorry about that I changed the code.. loadJSON needs a function as second argument, myjson(data.myjson) was wrong there. Now it should work.